# using bash command script in python

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script which when run, logs information on the terminal, i want to send this logging information to a text file,

To achieve this in the beginning of the file i am inserting

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['script', 'logfile'])
```

and at the end of the file,i put in,

```
subprocess.call(['exit'])
```

The problem with this is when it calls the first command`script logfile`,it terminates the script,

Any suggestions on how i could make this work would be really helpful,Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to run your `script logfile` directly?

Comment: if i use the command line to run `script logfile` first  and then run my script,That works! but i want it it integrated in my main script,if i run it separately,first i have to run  `script logfile` on the terminal ,then run my script and after its done,run `exit`.

Comment: It doesn't terminate the script; it is running a *new* shell whose input and output are logged. When you terminate *that* shell, your Python script will resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `subprocess.call` isn't returning until the shell spawned by `script` exits, at which point your Python script will resume.

The simplest way to do what you want is to call `script` itself with your Python script as an argument. Instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.call(['script', 'logfile'])

# Rest of your Python code

subprocess.call(['exit'])
```

you will use

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

if '_underscript' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['_underscript'] = "yes"
    cmd_args = ['script', 'logfile', 'python'] + sys.argv
    os.execvp('script', cmd_args)

# Rest of your Python code
```

The environment variable prevents your script from entering an infinite loop of re-running itself with `script`. When you run your Python script, it first checks its environment for a variable that should not yet exist. If it doesn't, it sets that variable, then runs `script` to re-run the Python script. `execvp` replaces your script with the call to `script`; nothing else in the Python script executes. This second time your script runs, the variable `_underscript` *does* exist, meaning the `if` block is skipped and the rest of your script runs as intended.

Comment: Hi chepner, Thanks for the reply,I have a doubt,I called my script by adding this snippet on the top of the file, i ran the file doing `python3 server.py` on the terminal , i keep getting the same behaviour as before meaning it doesnt run my script,Kindly let me know if i am missing something here,Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? With your code, the shell that appears after `script` runs is *not* the same shell from which you started the Python script.

Comment: Actually, I should have been more explicit: the `if '_underscript'` block *replaces* the need for your call to `subprocess.call(['script'])`. Are you running `script` twice?

Comment: Really, the simplest thing to do is just write the Python script normally, and make it the caller's responsibility to run it with `script logfile python yourScript.py ...` instead of `python yourScript.py ...`.

Comment: `cmd_args = ['script', 'logfile', 'python'] + sys.argv` could be improved to `cmd_args = ['script', 'logfile', sys.executable] + sys.argv`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like that's the expected behaviour of `subprocess.call(...)`. If you want to capture the output of the script to a file, you'll need to open a new file handler in write mode, and tell the `subprocess.call` where to direct the `stdout`, which is the terminal output you typically would see.

Try:

```
import subprocess
f = open('/tmp/mylogfile.log', 'w')
subprocess.call(['/path/to/script'], stdout=f)
f.close()
```

Then in the terminal you can run `tail /tmp/mylogfile.log` to confirm.

I'm not sure the last `exit` call is required for what you're trying to achieve.

You can read more in the python docs, depending which version of Python you're using. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

The file doesn't need to pre-exist. Hope that helps!

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it only records the outputs, not the inputs

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes that is correct, if you you can see one of the arugments in `subprocess.call` we're telling the `stdout` (in the terminal this is your standard out i.e. the text you see after executing a command) to write to variable `f` which is that file.

If you want the input too, you can add another argument `stdin=f` (where `stdin` means standard input) theoretically. As I've said, you can read the docs to check exactly how to do this.