# Is there a way to run the command "script <log file>" not directly on the terminal but from within my Python script?

Tags: python, logging, call

I want to record everything seen (input, output) on the terminal to a file. The problem is that I need to do that without using the command line. I have tried call():

```
from subprocess import call
call(["script", "logfile.log"])

#My code

call(["exit"])
```

but it just says

> Script started, file is logfile.log

on the terminal and the rest of my code won't work (there is a lot of user prompts)

Take note that I have also viewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288783/using-bash-command-script-in-python) already and tried the code from the answers there but it just does the same thing.

EDIT: Oh and also, I've read somewhere that the reason why it doesn't execute the rest of my code is that after calling script logfile, it starts a new shell? Is there any way for me to still do the same thing "script logfile" does without having to enter a new shell?

Comment: Your program could just do `subprocess.call(["script", "logfile.log", "-c", "MyRealProgram.py"])`, so that your code actually runs under the control of `script`.  If you insist on doing it all within a single process, you'd have to override `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr` so that they write any data to your log file as well as the original STDIO handles.

Comment: @jasonharper would I be needing 2 python scripts for this to work, then? One for the actual code I want to execute and one for this?